# 403 Forbidden when opening .pdf on website

Tags: html, pdf, http-status-code-403

I'm new to html and am trying to make a website for class.

When I reference my pdf file (that is saved in the www folder), I get:

403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /user/filename.pdf on this server.

My reference to the pdf looks like:

`<a href="filename.pdf">Filename</a>`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but .jpg 's open up fine...

Comment: This error indicates that a default document could not be found at the specified URL and that directory listings are not permitted.

Comment: try with full path like : "http://yourdomain/filename.pdf"

Comment: Have you made sure your pdf is readable to `o`thers? (Assuming a Linux/Unix system)

Comment: I referenced the full path and now when I click on the link it doesn't open at all.

Comment: @ulrichschwarz see above comment, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This could well be a `.htaccess` problem.  For example, if your .htaccess file contains this:

```
# but now allow just *certain* necessary files:
<FilesMatch "(?i).*\.(jpe?g|gif|webp|png|swf)$" >
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

you will need to add "pdf" as well.

Comment: thanks for the solution. It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with mine. I've been able to change the permission settings on the file on the server to enable access. I think that you may have to do the same.

Access the pdf on your server. Right Click and 'Change permissions' or the likes. It's probable that your pdf is set to restricted permissions. Mine enables me to then set it as available to "read" / "execute" / "write" by "user" / "group" or "world". If you select 'world' then you are effectively making it public and it should work, just fine.

Hope that this helps.

E.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to access filename.pdf in user directory. Put the pdf file in the same directory containing .jpg file. If it does not works, try full file path.

Comment: add more explanation to make answer clear to understand, accept

Comment: I referenced the full path and now when I click on the link it doesn't open at all.

Answer (score -1):

Linux when loading gives rights to read/edit the file. So, some users (perhaps your server) do not have read permission. You need to download the file with read permissions (just rebuild pdf) or change the permissions from the server. It helps for me.